# Where should I post this question about medical packaging?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted [this question at Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64655/why-medical-tablets-packed-in-random-order), but it was closed due to being off-topic.

> #### Why are medical tablets packed in random order?
>
> See this picture:
>
> [image]
>
> Is there any medical reason for this type of packing?

Is there a SE site that will suit this question?

Comment: Quite frankly, this is a rather a silly question. I don't really see where the answer to such a question would help anyway.

Comment: Don't know which site is suitable for this question, but the image is suitable for "You Had One Job" Meme. :)

Comment: If you watch *how* they're packaged the answer is obvious: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrAHTmq-DLE&t=3m32s

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Won't It won't make me nervous, I know they are **OCD** trigger pics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, not all questions fit the Q&A format well. As per the [help centre..](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your pills not being aligned isn't *actually* a problem. As such, there's no real site where this question would fit. It's probably a result of common sense industrial design.